# How do I peel garlic in bulk?

Tags: infusion

[image]I want to make some garlic and jalapeno infused oil. Maybe not jalapeno but some kind of Chile.

Answer (score 0):

Good ol' Chef John has a solution [right here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dc7w_PGSt9Y).

Basically, you want to enclose your garlic in some kind of container that lets them move around fairly easily. He uses two bowls, a commenter suggests a jar, I suppose it depends on the number of garlic cloves you want to peel.

Close the container then start shaking away, maybe for 20-30 seconds or longer once you get the hang of how long this method takes for your chosen clove count.